# Why can't I debug?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2005

When I was about to debug C++ program in VS2005,the program didn't stop at
the breakpoints.

The VS said"No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed".

What can I do?

Comment: Are you debugging an exe or a dll?

Comment: It happened to me after accidentally killing "mspdbsrv.exe". Killing the children of devenv.exe is a method I use sometimes to stop monstruos builds, when "Cancel build" is unresponsive.

Comment: Try to find out if ANOTHER INSTANCE (e.g. Release Version of your application) is running in Background!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to everybody.

Finally,I found a solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/503d3ded-976e-460e-b5f9-7e03454ed387/).

> To enable debugging:
>
> 1) Goto Project->HelloWorld Properties
>
> 2) On the left expand "Configuration Properties"
>
> 3) Expand "C/C++"
>
> 4) On the left, Select "General"
>
> 5) On the right, change "Debug Information Format" to "Program Database For Edit And Continue (/ZI)"
>
> 5) On the left, Select "Optimization"
>
> 6) On the right, change "Optimization" to "Disabled (/Od)"
>
> 7) On the left, expand "Linker"
>
> 8) On the left, select "Debugging"
>
> 9) On the right, change "Generate Debug Info" to "Yes"
>
> 10) Click ok
>
> 11) Set your breakpoints
>
> 12) Rebuild your application
>
> Also when running your application use Ctrl+F5 to build and run it, this keeps the console window open long enough for you to see your output.

Comment: You might want to put them in the post here in case that link ever moves.

Comment: I've been trying this and /ZI is incompatible with /clr and /clr:pure. So no good for WinForms or .NET based apps.

Answer (score 4):

A few steps to try:

1. Debug->Step Into (this will ensure you stop right after you start)
2. Debug->Windows->Modules
3. Look for your foo.exe on the list.
4. Check Symbol Status.  Does it say it is loaded?
5. If not, go to the path and ensure that:
    a)  there is a file called foo.pdb there
    b)  the timestamp on foo.pdb matches foo.exe (or is really close)

Comment: @Steve:There is no *.pdb in the Debug directory.

Comment: That's the root of your problem then.  It was probably generated somewhere.  Go find that and put it in the right place.

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason you don't have the right symbols (.pdb files) in the symbol path.  This could be for several reasons:

1)  Your binary was compiled more recently than the .pdb files.  Try recompiling everything.

2)  You are trying to debug a .dll and forgot to copy the .pdb files.  Copy those files too.

It's also possible that your code isn't being executed like you think.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're attaching to a process rather than running a conventional debug session? If you are indeed attaching to a process, it is important to ensure that binaries that you are trying to debug were built with the same source code currently open in your IDE.

Comment: Wrong source code should still break, just at strange places in the source.  If there is no break, it's probably a symbol issue, not a source code issue.

Comment: if the sourcecode isn't identical to the source it won't break (i have noticed this behaviour on my own)

Answer (score 1):

Complete clean and rebuild, making sure .pdb's get created?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem (using c# in VS) when trying to debug my unit tests.

You can add the following code that will launch a new instance of the debugger that will allow you yo step through your code like normal:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Comment: But I am debugging a C++ program , does it help?

Comment: Yes, you can use this with C++. Here's the documentation on the MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another possibility not yet covered by MainID:

When debugging, I actually started some program that would call into the classes I wanted to debug (it's some sort of add on). The called program is partly written in unmanaged C++. When I checked "Enable unmanaged code debugging" the error would come up (and subsequently the program crashed) because the program did not have any debug information.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem in WP7 by doing this:

1. Right click the project from Solution Explorer (<kbd>Ctrl+W+S</kbd>)
2. Select Rebuild.
3. Again, select the project, right click it and choose Deploy.
4. Start Debugging (F5)

I hope it will help you!