# debugging information cannot be found or does not match visual studio's

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I copied an existing project and renamed the folder. Now I get this error when I try to compile the application

> debugging information cannot be found or does not match. No symbols loaded.
>   Do you want to continue debugging ?

If I click yes, it compiles and runs fine. But now I have to deal with that message. Just curious about what I change in the projects properties to get it to stop.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The main reason is that you don't have a matching pdb and exe.

Some possible solutions:

- You are compiling in release instead of debug
- You need to clean/build or rebuild
- You don't have your pdb files being generated in the same directory as the exe
- You have a mismatching pdb, maybe the copied source is newer than today's date and something isn't building properly.
- Try cleaning out all debug object files
- You are attaching to a process that you started from a different location from where your build exe and pdb exist
- Restart Visual Studio

Comment: More than 10 years on, "Restart visual studio" is STILL the fix for this. Infuriating

Answer (score 70):

You probably have deactivated the debugging information for your project:

- Right click on your project -> Properties
- Configuration properties -> Linker -> Debugging
- Switch "Generate Debug Info" from No to Yes

Rebuild your project and retry, it should now run without the message :)

Comment: @NicholasGuillaume I am running in release and getting this error. I don't _want_ to generate debug information. Is there a way that I can Visual Studio not to try to run with debug info?

Comment: @JonathanMee Not as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Being forced to work with Visual Studio 2013 on a project and coming from Qt Creator (if you don't have to work with VS do try Qt Creator out!) I find it unbelievable that you configure your project to be compiled for debugging (set Debug instead of Release in the project configuration) and yet the "Generate Debug Info" is disabled!!! This is one of the most stupid things I have witnessed in a software product. -_-

Comment: my "Configuration Properties" has only one option which is "Configuration" I have no idea why

Answer (score 10):

This happens to me every now and then, while debugging code and making changes it seems like visual studio caches the pdb information and sometimes it gets stuck. Doing a Rebuild solution, deleting the pdb and creating a new one doesn't fix the problem.

Of course I do have the generate debug information on and all that it's needed, specially since this happens while debugging the code several times.

Visual Studio seems to be happy with the in-memory pdb and refuses to update it, regardless of time-stamps or even size changes in the pdb.

The only way to reset this is to exit Visual Studio (the IDE) and restart it again.

In some rare occurrences, the IDE might be still running in the background (process explorer shows it there) and might hold the handle to the file open. You can kill the process before restarting the IDE.

Good Luck

Answer (score 7):

I just encountered this error in VS2012. It is definitely caused by a bug in Visual Studio, which reveals itself in situations when the local PDB file of the main project has the same name as the final PDB file for the entire executable (even if the two are located in different directories!)

Consider this example.

Solution consists of three projects: `main`, `a`, and `b`. `main` is the top-level project for the executable, while `a` and `b` are libraries linked into `main`.

In all three projects `$(IntDir)` variable is set to `$(SolutionDir)\$(Configuration)\$(ProjectName)\`. This means that project `main` dumps its intermediate files to `Debug\main\`, project `a` - to `Debug\a\` and so on.

In `C/C++ -> Output Files` settings all three projects have `Program Database File Name` value set to `$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pdb`. This means that project `main` generates its local PDB file as `Debug\main\main.pdb`, project `b` as `Debug\b\b.pdb` and so on.

Finally, in `Linker -> Debugging` settings of project `main` the `Generate Program Database File` value is set to `$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb`. This means that the global PDB file for the entire executable will be generated as `Debug\main.pdb`.

Note that in this setup each PDB file is generated in its own, separate directory.

In this setup you will get **Debugging information cannot be found or does not match** error if you attempt to run the program under the debugger. And if you take a look at the `Debug\main.pdb` file (which will exist), you will notice that it is exactly the same as `Debug\main\main.pdb` file! I.e. somehow the local PDB for `main` managed to overwrite what was supposed to be the global PDB for the final executable. I.e. the debugger is right to complain that the PDB file is "wrong". It is indeed wrong.

Again, in the above setup the final global PDB somehow gets overwritten by local PDB of the top project. I don't know why it happens. It appears to be a bug. (Note that even though these PDB files have the same name, they are generated in different directories, i.e. they should not conflict.)

A workaround that fixes this issue is to give the local PDB of project `main` a different name. For example, just go to `C/C++ -> Output Files` for the `main` project and change `Program Database File Name` value to `$(IntDir)$(TargetName)_local.pdb` (or to `$(IntDir)12345.pdb` if you so desire). This will eliminate the conflict and solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Enable PDB creation by:

Right click on `MyProject > Properties > Debugging`:

- `C/C++ > General > Debug Information Output = Program Database (/Zi)`
- `Linker > Debugging > Generate Debug Info = Yes (/DEBUG)`

Clean MyProject, restart Visual Studio (just to be sure), rebuild MyProject.
The output folder should then contain *.pdb files.

If you debug optimized/release code consider switching off optimization via

- `C++ > Optimization > Optmization = Disabled (/Od)`

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio is not required!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and tried all above mentioned solutions but it couldn't help me.
Then I found a new solution randomly and it worked.

Solution is that,in case you are having many projects in a solution then you should mark any one (specific one which you have to decide) project as a "Set as Startup Project".
Right click on that specific project and click "Set as Startup Project".

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

The `pdb` or Program Database file appears to be missing (basically, the path has changed and can no longer be found by the compiler). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540536/why-cant-i-debug) related post for additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the reason was that I had run one of the projects of my solution in a different process and that process couldn't be killed. I didn't think much of it. So when I was building the solution in a separate environment one of the pdb files didn't match so at the end I couldn't load any of the pdb files. I just restarted my computer and that fixed it.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio can fix one instance of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project in the solution browser => Clean => Build. 
That is if your build generates a .pdb at all (look in your target dir)
If not, you should enable debug by the steps mentioned in other posts

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there are other reasons like .pdb / .exe file mismatch, something were not built / rebuilt, but I had similar case in Visual studio 2013 -

Something to do with virtual inline function - so I suspect.

In my case debugger were jumping in a middle of another C++ function, not the one which was called. Jump was off source code by 11 source code lines, but I cannot explain why much miscalculation happened. By simple rearranging functions I've got rid of this problem.

May be needs more detailed analysis why 11 lines shift happened originally.

Haven't seen this kind of behavior in any other visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has bothered me for a long time. AnT's anwser is very helpful. The main idea is **Don't have any two pdb files have the same name**, even they are not in the same directory.

This is my situation: I have tow projects name "FooBar" and "FooBarDll", the first one is an exe, and the second one is a dll. I set both projects **Target Name** to be "FooBar", so that they will generate "FooBar.exe" and "FooBar.dll" respectively.

Then I set

1. "General -> Intermediate Directory" to be "$(OutDir)\$(ProjectName)\"
2. "C/C++ -> Output Files -> Program Database File Name" to be "$(IntDir)$(TargetName).pdb"
3. "Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Program Database File" to be "$(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb"

So I get these files:

1. Debug\FooBar.exe
2. Debug\FooBar.pdb //C++ pdb
3. Debug\FooBar\FooBar.pdb //Linker pdb
4. Debug\FooBar.dll
5. Debug\FooBar.pdb  // C++ pdb **again!**
6. Debug\FooBarDll\FooBar.pdb // Linker pdb

My solution is replacing every "TargetName" with "ProjectName", then I will get:

1. Debug\FooBar.exe
2. Debug\FooBar.pdb //C++ pdb
3. Debug\FooBar\FooBar.pdb //Linker pdb
4. Debug\FooBar.dll
5. Debug\FooBarDll.pdb  // C++ pdb
6. Debug\FooBarDll\FooBarDll.pdb // Linker pdb

Then there is no conflict!

Give C/C++ pdb a suffix may be better, like: "C/C++ -> Output Files -> Program Database File Name" to be "$(IntDir)$(ProjectName)_C.pdb"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sburke/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code/) helped me solved the problem, by rename "symsrv.no" to "symsrv.yes" in VS IDE folder.

Answer (score -1):

Curious, it happens to me that I needed to change the folder name from:

```
...\Custom Librarry (MyDll.dll(
```

to

```
...\Custom Librarry (MyDll.dll)
```

just by closing the parenthesis it worked !