# Release Project with No Debug Info Warning

Tags: c++, visual-studio, executable, release, debug-information

I am building and running my project in Release and I do not want to build with Debug info.

But when I run the project I get the same error as in this question: [debugging information cannot be found or does not match visual studio's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2322876/2642059)

> Debugging information for 'foo.exe' cannot be found or does not match. Binary was not built with debug information.

How can I tell Visual Studio 2010 to stop trying to find Debug info in Release?

EDIT:

I'm working in C++.
It's interesting, I did start noticing this when I linked in a .dll built from another one of my projects. I wonder if it could have to do with this?

Comment: Stop running it through the IDE as if debugging. Run the exe outside of VS. That's only an informational message.

Comment: @RogerRowland I don't get an error, but that's not the desired solution. I don't understand why just in this project it's trying to load Debug info.

Comment: If you want to run via the IDE, choose "Start without debugging" CTRL+F5 rather than just F5.

Comment: On all your projects make sure Debug Information Format is set to None, and in linker settings Generate Debug Info is No

Comment: @RogerRowland Is there not a setting for the project to tell the debugger not to attach in Release?

Comment: Well, if you press F5, you're *asking* it to attach the debugger! The setting is in your fingertips ;-) Just use CTRL+F5 to start *without* attaching the debugger.

Comment: @RogerRowland So this is the only project that I get this warning pop up on. I don't understand why. Note that Configuration Properties>Debugging>Attach is set to "No"

Comment: If it's a Release build, and you have *not* created a PDB, and you launch via the debugger, you *will* get that message. Do your other projects have PDBs? Are they different project types? It's different between native and managed code. Is this maybe a .NET project that loads a native DLL?

Comment: Have you disabled the option `Debugging->Warn if no symbols on launch` ?

Comment: @stijn That also "Fixes" it... I'm just trying to understand why it's a problem _just_ in this project. I don't need to do that for any of my other projects and I'd like to figure out what I've done wrong here.

Comment: Well you should probably add extra information about that project then. Language? Output type? Differences with other projects (compare project files side by side in a text editor or so)? Maybe the other projects do have pdb files? and so on

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you start your program by clicking on the green arrow next to the build configuration window. By doing this, Visual Studio will always try to run your code in the debugger - even if you compiled it in relase mode.

Try starting your progam by pressing Ctrl + F5 - This should start the .exe without any intervention of the debugger.

Comment: "Strg + F5"? I'm trying "Shift + F5" But nothing happens.

Comment: I am sorry - that was the German name for the key. Of course I meant. Ctrl + F5.

Comment: Maybe change it back since most of us English speakers have English keyboards. Incidentally this is the solution suggested by [Roger Rowland](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2065121/roger-rowland)

Comment: Changed it, but i see it was not the solution you were looking for. Unfortunately I don't know why it only happens in this particular project.