# The OpenCV 2.4.9 (64bit lib compiled by visual studio 2008) can not work because of "debug information can not be found"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I'm doing some works with Open CV 2.4.9. I use cmake(32 bit) to build a visual studio 2008 solution (specified Visual Studio 9 2008 win64 generator for this project and select "Use default native compilers), because there's no prebuilt lib for visual studio 2008. When I configure the compiled 64 bit lib for my test project. I found this: when I launch debug in Debug x64 mode, I got "debug information can not be found..." and the test code crashed. When I change to Release x64 mode, I got the same message but when I click "Yes" button to continue, the test code worked. 
  Then I try to solve it. I set the Debug 64 properties->C++->general->debug information format->Program Database (/Zi) but it didn't work. By the way, the 32 bit lib can work but I need use the 64 bit lib to develop a 64 bit app.
  Thanks for paying attention!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the required debug libraries linked ?

Comment: yeah. I configured the linked lib and set additional debug libs

Comment: and I made a mistake that with debug x64 mode, I got: "debug assertion failed!" If I launch debug in release x64 mode, I got: "Debugging information for 'Test.exe' cannot be found or does not match. Binary was not built with debug information.'

Comment: and I made a mistake that with debug x64 mode, I got: "debug assertion failed! Program:...isual Studio 2008\Projects\TestOpenCV2.4.9\x64\Debug\Test.exe File: f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_64_amd64\crt\src\fopen.c Line:54 Expression:(file != NULL) " If I launch debug in release x64 mode, I got: "Debugging information for 'Test.exe' cannot be found or does not match. Binary was not built with debug information.'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322876/debugging-information-cannot-be-found-or-does-not-match-visual-studios  have you looked into this?

Comment: Sorry for not replying in time, I'm reading it. BTW, I found another method last time, which need to replace the additional lib for release version which doesn't contain "d" in the lib file name. It worked round but not a perfect solution.

Comment: Hi, TurboTurd. Thanks for your help and I fix the release without debug information by referring to the link you offered. But, I still can not find a perfect method to solve debug assertion failure. Maybe I need stop study this issue and use the work-around method and finish my work first.