# Debugging information for 'WebDev.WebSer40.exe' cannot found or does not match. Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

What could the solution for this error. I got this warning when i try to run the code in debug mode.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Upvote the answer also please )) Reputation )

Comment: @MikroDe Hey Sure. Your answer helped me. But i don't have enough reputation to upvote. Would you please upvote for my question if the question is clear and people can identify the solution easily next time.I would also get a chance to upvote to you because my reputation will become 17. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question very similar to your one [Why can't I debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540536/why-cant-i-debug) are alredy answered.

The reasons for your PDB problem eplained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2322910/502950):

- You are compiling in release instead of debug
- You need to clean/build or rebuild
- You don't have your pdb files being generated in the same directory as the exe
- You have a mismatching pdb, maybe the copied source is newer than today's date and something isn't building properly.
- Try cleaning out all debug object files
- You are attaching to a process that you started from a different location from where your build exe and pdb exist