# Visual Studio: Debugging Information for "java.exe" cannot be found or does not match. Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: java, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I encountered this error message when I tried to debug my code under Debug.
[image]

The project is mainly composed of .h, .cpp, and JNI files wrapped inside a Java program.
I tried methods such as clean/build//rebuild, made sure using the Debug ver. instead of Release ver., rebooting OS, suppressing the message by tweaking Properties, etc. (Reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322876/debugging-information-cannot-be-found-or-does-not-match-visual-studios) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540536/why-cant-i-debug)) None of them worked in my case. [This source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937707/error-message-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file) also suggests to ignore the error. Two questions remain for me:

1) The 1st link suggests

> You don't have your pdb files being generated in the same directory as the exe

However, my exe file is java.exe, which locates in Java/jdkx.x.x_xx/bin. I find it difficult to believe a debugger should "contaminate" a jdk directory. Does this suggestion apply to my case? Can we tell VS where to generate the pdb file?

2) What difference does it make if I ignore this error? Should I check "Don't show this dialog again"?

My appreciation to you in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: I try to "get the process to work when I click the 'Start Debugging (F5)' button."
I replied in a very conservative way because the code I have is a legacy code and I am also new to VS. I think there is something more to your question which I am ignorant of.

Comment: Visual Studio debugging requires symbol files to be present, and that's what the first dialogue asks for. Unless Oracle provides the symbol files which they don't, you cannot use Visual Studio to debug a Java application.

Comment: My program has JNI files which call Java functions; however, all files are in c and c++ so I don't think java.exe should be called. Yet, java.exe seemed to be invoked. hmm